# What can be reason TFS 2015 is not running unit tests while passing MS Build arguments

Tags: tfs-2015

I am setting up new tfs build definition using Web based build definition. I am getting an issue with the unit test cases.

If I run the build without passing any MS Build Arguments, my build is getting done successfully and it's running all test cases included in solution. 
But when I pass MS Build arguments, it's not running any unit test cases - just ignoring it and going to next build step. What can be it?

I am building .NET Solution and passing MS BUILD ARGUMENTS AS

```
(/p:DeployOnBuild=true /P:PackageTempRootDir=\Release /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site";DefaultPackageFileName=SampleApp.zip /p:OutputPath="$(Build.BinariesDirectory)\$(BuildPlatform)\$(BuildConfiguration)")
```

Is there any connection between these two (MS Build arguments and Unit test) cases?

I am not getting any error, the build is also successfully passing in both cases. But unit test are not getting executed.

Here is test step output:

```
2017-02-14T22:35:06.6488286Z Executing the powershell script: E:\agnt\tasks\VSTest\1.0.32\VSTest.ps1

2017-02-14T22:35:07.4248374Z ##[debug]Calling Invoke-VSTest for all test assemblies

2017-02-14T22:35:07.6348369Z Working folder: E:\agnt\_work\39

2017-02-14T22:35:07.6348369Z Executing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe "E:\agnt\_work\39\s\CaseAPI\Main\packages\Agero.TestRunner.1.0.0\lib\net45\Agero.TestsRunner.NUnit.dll"  /TestCaseFilter:"TestCategory!=Ignore" /EnableCodeCoverage /logger:trx

2017-02-14T22:35:07.8428336Z Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 14.0.25420.1

2017-02-14T22:35:07.8438332Z Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

2017-02-14T22:35:07.9678332Z Starting test execution, please wait...

2017-02-14T22:35:08.0108349Z Warning: Using Isolation mode to run the tests as diagnostic data adapters were enabled in the runsettings. Use the /inIsolation parameter to suppress this warning.

2017-02-14T22:35:16.0528901Z Attachments:

2017-02-14T22:35:16.0538895Z   E:\agnt\_work\39\TestResults\6eaffd7e-b2ac-4bc4-b356-41a2fda7bad9\csr1_B-TFSBC001WV 2017-02-14 17_35_10.coverage

2017-02-14T22:35:16.2028915Z Information: Additionally, you can try specifying '/UseVsixExtensions' command if the test discoverer & executor is installed on the machine as vsix extensions and your installation supports vsix extensions. Example: vstest.console.exe myTests.dll /UseVsixExtensions:true

2017-02-14T22:35:16.3698948Z ##[warning]No results found to publish.
```

Any advice/help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have changed the OutputPath to `$(Build.BinariesDirectory)\$(BuildPlatform)\$(BuildConfiguration)`, so you also need to specify the test assembly in VS test task to: `$(Build.BinariesDirectory)\$(BuildPlatform)\$(BuildConfiguration)\*test*.dll`:

[image]

Comment: Awesome!!! It worked. Now i got it. because of I changed output path, it was looking in different location. Thank you for help